# What is the max number of points I can put in an n-dimensional ball with radius 1, so that the distance between any two points is $\ge 1$?

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

I want calculate max number of points that I can put in an n-dimensional ball with radius 1, so that the distance between any two points is $\ge 1$. I want get the exact formula or lower bound for number of points that depends on dimensionality. I write a program that try placed maximum points to the ball with radius 1 and I get so far:
\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline \text{dim} & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\ \hline \text{num points} & 3 & 7 & \ge13 & \ge23 & \ge 37 & \ge 59 & \ge 87\\ \hline  \end{array}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your formula works for $n=1$ or $2$. What layout do you have in mind for your $15$ points when $n=3$?

Comment: Nothing :) I know how place $13$ points in $3$ dimension, but I suppose it's possible place $15$

Comment: So your hypothesis is just based on two data points? That is not very convincing!

Comment: I think it's also works for zero dimension too :)

Comment: But why not, for instance, $n^2-n+1$? That even matches your $13$ points for $n=3$.

Comment: Yeah, you right my hypothesis is rubbish. I find out that for 4-dimensions answer greater than $23$

Comment: has some connections to molecular geometry

Comment: You can try an energy minimization simulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this is essentially the [kissing number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number) problem, with an extra point at the center of the ball. (In your problem, you don't *have* to put a point at the center of the ball, but if you put a point in the ball's interior that is located away from the center, then you've eliminated a large region of the ball's surface that isn't counterbalanced by opening a bunch of space in its interior. I strongly suspect that makes that tactic sub-optimal, but it would be worth verifying.)

If you put a point at the ball's center, then the remaining points will be on the ball's surface, and they must be separated by distance $1$, which are exactly the tangent points of balls in the kissing number problem. Therefore, the answer to your question will be one plus the answer to the kissing number problem: that is,

$$ n_1 = \kappa(1)+1 = 2+1 = 3 $$
$$ n_2 = \kappa(2)+1 = 6+1 = 7 $$
$$ n_3 = \kappa(3)+1 = 12+1 = 13 $$
$$ n_4 = \kappa(4)+1 = 24+1 = 25 $$

Values are also known for dimensions $8$ and $24$, due to the symmetries of the $E_8$ and Leech lattices:

$$ n_8 = \kappa(8)+1 = 240+1 = 241 $$
$$ n_{24} = \kappa(24)+1 = 196\,560+1 = 196\,561 $$

Even where values are not precisely known, we may draw from the lower and upper bounds established for the kissing number problem—for example:

$$ n_5 = \kappa(5)+1 \in \{41, 42, \ldots, 45\} $$
$$ n_6 = \kappa(6)+1 \in \{73, 74, \ldots, 79\} $$
$$ n_7 = \kappa(7)+1 \in \{127, 128, \ldots, 135\} $$

and so forth. Incidentally, each of these is consistent with your lower bounds.

This is a problem with deep connections to coding theory, and indeed part of the proof of the four-dimensional case draws upon a clever modification by Oleg Musin to a coding theory approach sometimes called the Delsarte method. See Pfender and Ziegler, "[Kissing Numbers, Sphere Packings, and Some Unexpected Proofs](http://www.ams.org/notices/200408/fea-pfender.pdf)," in *Notices of the AMS*, Vol. $51$, pp. $873$–$883$. If I get the motivation at some point, I may come back and sketch out the Delsarte method for two dimensions. This case is of course easy to establish *ad hoc*, but showing the Delsarte method for two dimensions makes the approach easier to understand.

Casselman, "[The Difficulties of Kissing in Three Dimensions](https://www.ams.org/notices/200408/comm-cass.pdf)," also gives some interesting history behind this problem, including the somewhat surprising fact that the story of Newton and Gregory's discussion of the three-dimensional case is often distorted! I had always heard (initially from Martin Gardner's retelling in his *Mathematical Games* column) that Newton thought $\kappa(3) = 12$ while Gregory thought $\kappa(3) = 13$, but that is an oversimplification. See the article for more details.